# get images from memory card and store in drawable folder

Tags: android, image, drawable, sd-card

I made a application in which many images are shown,

all images are pre-stored in drawable folder of resources,

but if i want to add new picture then how can i do this,

it should read from memory card but only once, after that it automatically load.

Comment: Let me guess... nPuzzle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to upload images yourself to the app instead of letting user use images or..?

If it's you, who should upload new images, you can download them to the app with a check if there are new ones.

If it's the user, you can check their gallery on the sd card, but unfortunatly I don't think it's possible to store these in the drawable folder.

Answer (score 1):

You mean you want a dynamic drawable folder? You cannot do that since APK file is read only...

Answer (score 1):

you cant do this, because it is an impossible act, Drawable folder is meant to make the Application Environment when it is deployed, it is a one way process. you can copy Drawble image to external path