# How do you add a gallery image (user Image) to your drawable folder?

Tags: android, android-drawable

so I want to store the image I got from the user's gallery into my drawable folder, but I'm not sure how to do that? Can someone help me with that!! I have the image's path, but I want to be a file in my drawable folder.

Thanks.

```
private void grabImage()
{
    Intent imageGetter = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(imageGetter, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data)
    {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};//Array size of 1, and we put in a string
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        user_image_path = cursor.getString(columnIndex);//here we have our image path.
        cursor.close();
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(user_image_path));
    }

    //Sending our images.
    sendInformation.putExtra("imagePath", user_image_path);

}
```

So after I grabbed the image and send it, I also want to know how to convert that image path string into a Drawable file I can always reference. It's a VERY long story why I want to do that, but that's just what I have to do :/. If someone can provide example code that'd be amazing!

Comment: The drawable folder is a compiled resource embedded into your apk. You cannot change it at runtime.

Comment: [link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6869773/get-images-from-memory-card-and-store-in-drawable-folder

Answer (score 0):

Drawable folders are compiled in your apk and cannot be modified at runtime. If you are looking to store the image you can always use the app's sandbox directory(i.e /data/data/application_package). Files stored here will not be listed in gallery or any other explorer without root permissions.